# How do you read/write audio files using the libsndfile C++ wrapper?

Tags: c++, c, audio, libsndfile

*[libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/)* is a C library for reading and writing WAV files, and it also includes a C++ wrapper, which I'd like to use.

However, although the C API documentation is very thorough, I cannot figure out how to use the C++ wrapper to read audio files (though there are [examples on the web about *writing*](http://parumi.wordpress.com/2007/12/16/how-to-write-wav-files-in-c-using-libsndfile/)).

Is there any actual documentation or examples using this API? Or should I just give up on using this wrapper, and instead use the C API directly?

Comment: What, Google not available in your country? First result for `libsndfile` says: "A C library for reading and writing files containing sampled sound. Project news, features list, API reference, FAQ, and download. [LGPL]". The same website is the linked to in the article you cited, underneath the very first mention of the text "libsndfile".

Comment: This Question is specifically about the C++ api that is included with libsndfile. `sndfile.hh`

Comment: @LeeG: Sorry, that's true. My lack of familiarity with the library meant I did not pick that up from your question, which I've now edited to make a little clearer. Indeed there doesn't seem to be official documentation for the C++ wrapper. For what it's worth, that seems to have been the rationale behind that blog post. +1

Answer (score 4):

There is an example program here: https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile/blob/master/examples/sndfilehandle.cc

Comment: Interesting, the way files are read in the example isn't quite what I'd expect. If I have the chance I'll play around with this example this weekend and see if this works correctly.